# Is order of features in LibSVM feature vectors important?

Tags: libsvm, svm

I am considering using [LibSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) and I am creating the required feature vectors.
In almost all the example data there is an order for the features for example:

```
+1 1:3 2:1 3:5 4:2 10:8
```

Was wondering if this ordering is important, for example:

```
+1 4:2 10:8 2:1 1:3 3:5
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although both of your notations are equivalent, LibSVM requires the Feature-IDs to be sorted ascendingly - I suppose this has I/O-reasons.